# How to set layout page for view runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one application in which I require to set layout file of view runtime depend on parameter. Is it possible in MVC 4 with Razor?

Comment: Show what you have tired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Layout ='Path to layout file in shared folder', with this you can change your layout file

```
@{ 
   var layoutPath ="DefaultPath";
   switch(Parameter){
      case "value1": 
         layoutpath='path1';
         break;
      case "value2" : 
         layoutpath='path2';
         break;
   }
   Layout = layoutpath; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .cshtml file at the start of the page:

```
@{if (Parameter==value)
{
  Layout = "oneLayout";
}
else
{
  Layout="secondLayoutPath";
}
```